# How to calculate a time period until a condition is matched

Tags: r, date, time

I need to calculate a time of consecutive dates, until the difference of time between two consecutive dates is greater than 13 seconds.

For example, in the data frame create with the code shown below, the column test has the time difference between the dates. What I need is events of time between lines with test > 13 seconds.

```
# Create a vector of dates with a random time difference in seconds between records
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:02"), as.POSIXct("2020-01-02 00:00:02"), by = "2 sec")
dates <- dates + sample(15, length(dates), replace = T)

# Create a data.frame
data <- data.frame(id = 1:length(dates), dates = dates)

# Create a test field with the time difference between each date and the next
data$test <- c(diff(data$dates, lag = 1), 0)

# Delete the zero and negative time
data <- data[data$test > 0, ]

head(data)
```

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Comment: The sample data you posted will only have a maximum time between events of 10 seconds (because of `sample(10, length(dates), replace = T)`). Once you fix that, just use `data <- data[data$test > 13, ]`

Comment: Thanks!, I changed the sample x to 15.

Comment: is something not working as expected with `data <- data[data$test > 13, ]`?

Comment: Hi, thanks! But this is not what I whant. I need to calculate the time between the values 13. Fo example, each time the 13 appears, i need to know the time since the last 13 and the next 13, I need events of time beteew the 13, like blocks.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want, can you post an example of what you expect?

Comment: Look the image added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to your desired result we need to define 'blocks' of observation. Each block is splitted where `test` is greater than 13.
We start identifying the `split_point`, and then using the `rle` function we can assign an ID to each block.
Then we can filter out the `split_point`, and summarize the remaining blocks. Once with the sum of seconds, then with the min of the event dates.

```r
split_point <- data$test <=13
# Find continuous blocks
block_str <- rle(split_point)
# Create block IDs
data$block <- rep(seq_along(block_str$lengths), block_str$lengths)
data <- data[split_point, ] # Remove split points

# Summarize
final_df <- aggregate(test ~ block, data = data, FUN = sum)
dtevent <- aggregate(dates ~ block, data= data, FUN=min)

# Join the two summaries
final_df$DatetimeEvent <- dtevent$dates

head(final_df)
#>   block test       DatetimeEvent
#> 1     1 101  2020-01-01 00:00:09
#> 2     3 105  2020-01-01 00:01:11
#> 3     5 277  2020-01-01 00:02:26
#> 4     7  46  2020-01-01 00:04:58
#> 5     9  27  2020-01-01 00:05:30
#> 6    11 194  2020-01-01 00:05:44
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Using `dplyr`for convenience sake:

```r
library(dplyr)

final_df <- data %>%
  mutate(split_point = test <= 13,
         block = with(rle(split_point), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
  group_by(block) %>%
  filter(split_point) %>%
  summarise(DateTimeEvent = min(dates), TotalTime = sum(test))

final_df
#> # A tibble: 1,110 x 3
#>    block DateTimeEvent       TotalTime
#>    <int> <dttm>              <drtn>   
#>  1     1 2020-01-01 00:00:06 260 secs 
#>  2     3 2020-01-01 00:02:28 170 secs 
#>  3     5 2020-01-01 00:04:11 528 secs 
#>  4     7 2020-01-01 00:09:07  89 secs 
#>  5     9 2020-01-01 00:10:07  37 secs 
#>  6    11 2020-01-01 00:10:39 135 secs 
#>  7    13 2020-01-01 00:11:56  50 secs 
#>  8    15 2020-01-01 00:12:32 124 secs 
#>  9    17 2020-01-01 00:13:52  98 secs 
#> 10    19 2020-01-01 00:14:47  83 secs 
#> # … with 1,100 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

(results are different because `reprex` recreates the data each time)

Comment: Hi GGamba, Thanks a lot! Your code solve my question. I wrote a loop to create the blocks, but it was consuming a lot of time. My data set has 7M of observations.